# How recursion works with undo?

Tags: python, recursion

How does the code after recursion line work?
Once the code hits the line

```
sim_score = self.minimax(other_player,letter)
```

the function repeats itself, but what happens with the next line of code.
In my code I want to undo whatever recursion line did, namely UNDO THE MOVE.
Does it happen only after recusion is completed or during each recursion?

```
def minimax(self,player,letter):
    ...
    ...
    return something
    ...
    ...
    for possible_move in self.available_spaces():
        self.board[possible_move] = player # MAKE MOVE
        if self.winner_check(player) == True:
            self.current_winner = player

        sim_score = self.minimax(other_player,letter) # recursion

        # UNDO MOVE
        self.board[possible_move] = self.save_board[possible_move]
```

Comment: A recursive call is not different from a "normal" function call: it must return first before the next statement is executed, and this is what happens also when there is a deeper recursive call. You question is quite vague. I have no idea what you mean with *"during each recursion"*.

Comment: Do you want to undo what the recursion did, or do you want to undo what the "MAKE MOVE" line did?

Comment: Also not that - as written - there is no recursion. Your 'return something' line will terminate the function before any recursive call can happen.